# Xamarin iOS subview created inside custom UIView class not showing up

Tags: uiview, xamarin.ios

I have a custom UIView class, where I would like to add a bunch of subviews. This should be a simple task but I can't seem to figure out why my views are not showing up on the UI.

The examples and tutorials out there are pretty straight forward and I believe I have implemented my code correctly. I have added a breakpoint at `AddSubview` and the container has a size.

The UIViewController class already has a background image added it via the storyboard.

Can someone help me see what I'm probably missing? I know it's something small.

Below is my code:

**The custom view class**

```
public class RotaryWheel : UIView
{
    int numberOfSections;

  public RotaryWheel(CGRect frame,int sections): base(frame)
    {
       numberOfSections = sections;

       DrawWheel();

    }

  public void DrawWheel()
   {
       // derive the center x and y
          float centerX = (float)(Frame.Width / 2);
          float centerY = (float)(Frame.Height / 2);

        container = new UIView();
        container.Frame = new RectangleF(centerX, centerY, 100, 100);
        container.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        AddSubview(container);
   }
}
```

**The UIViewController** class where I initialize the view

```
  public partial class HomePageController : UIViewController
  {
      public override void LoadView()
      {
        base.LoadView();

         rotaryWheel = new RotaryWheel(new CGRect(20f, (float)(View.Frame.Height / 2), (float)View.Frame.Size.Width, (float)View.Frame.Height / 2f), 7);
         View.AddSubview(rotaryWheel);

      }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all, refer to [loadView()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview). As the documentation mentioned

> If you want to perform any additional initialization of your views, do so in the viewDidLoad() method.

We should never initialize subviews in `LoadView`, so I try to move that code to `viewDidLoad`

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    RotaryWheel rotaryWheel = new RotaryWheel(new CGRect(20f, (float)(View.Frame.Height / 2), (float)View.Frame.Size.Width, (float)View.Frame.Height / 2f), 7);
    View.AddSubview(rotaryWheel);
}
```

But it looks like this, the subviews doesn't locate as expected.

[image]

After moving that code to `ViewDidAppear`, the problem disappeared.

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

    if(rotaryWheel  == null){
        rotaryWheel = new RotaryWheel(new CGRect(20f, (float)(View.Frame.Height / 2), (float)View.Frame.Size.Width, (float)View.Frame.Height / 2f), 7);
        View.AddSubview(rotaryWheel);
    }
}
```

[image]

#### Summary:

The real size of `View` comes out in method `ViewDidAppear`. If you don't use autoLayout , you should manage the View `Frame` carefully.

And about why you didn't see the subview, I guess you selected the iphone4 ,iPhone 5 or iPhone5S simulator for test , the screen width is 320, you create RotaryWheel with X= 20 , centerX is 300 in method `LoadView`, so it is displayed out of screen.

Comment: Hi @Cole. Your answer definitely pointed me in the right direction. Thanks. I'm accepting it.